# DirectX12 - ExecuteCommandLists and Present function

Tags: directx-12

I found that in the Microsoft sample example:

```
void D3D12HelloTriangle::OnRender()
{
// Record all the commands we need to render the scene into the command list.
PopulateCommandList();

// Execute the command list.
ID3D12CommandList* ppCommandLists[] = { m_commandList.Get() };
m_commandQueue->ExecuteCommandLists(_countof(ppCommandLists), ppCommandLists);

// Present the frame.
ThrowIfFailed(m_swapChain->Present(1, 0));

WaitForPreviousFrame();
}
```

How does is actually work ? ExecuteCommandLists is a asynchronous function call, so it means the code execution will continue and it hits Present function.

What will happen after Present call ? Let's say, GPU is still drawing, working and present is called. Is Present sychronous call ? It cannot present buffer when gpu is still drawing. Is that correct ? Could someone explain what's happening here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Present is also an asynchronous command that tells the GPU to start scanning out (displaying) from the next buffer in the swap chain. You don't have to worry about the GPU not having finished executing all previously issued work (on the graphics command queue) before the 'Flip' takes place.